# Retrieve multiple values via SELECT Option in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, html, django-views

I'm using Python(3.6) & Django(1.10) and need multiple values from a drop-down option selection.

Here's what I have tried:
**From template:**

```
<select id="slc" name="cluster">
<option value="{{cluster.name}}#{{cluster.zone}}"> {{ cluster.name }}</option>
</select>
```

**From views.py:**

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      if request.method == 'POST':
         post_data = request.POST.copy()
         form = forms.ClusterForm(post_data)
         if form.is_valid():
            project = form.cleaned_data['project']
            blocks = request.POST.get('cluster').split('#')
```

How can i get the values for **name** & **zone**.I already take a deep look at the existing questions but couldn't solve my issue.So, don't mark this question as a duplicate, please!

Help me, Please!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's would be better if you put {{cluster.id}} to the value in a template, then you would be able to fetch cluster object from a database in your views.py.

Comment: I don't need to retrieve cluster object from the database, it's coming from an API and from views it's again going to pass to another API, and also there's no id attribute for cluster object is available.

Comment: In `get` method of view class, retrieve the `{name: "name", zone:"zone"}` from API and add it to context dict to be rendered in template. Alternatively, you can create a form in view itself with required choices and labels using the data from API call. In `post` method, extract data from form and send it wherever you want to send it.

Comment: I'm using a Form, see the updated code, please!

Answer (score 0):

At first change the template code like this:

```
<select id="slc" name="cluster">
<option value="{{cluster.name}}"> {{ cluster.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Then in the view:

```
post_data = request.POST.copy()
cluster_object = Clustermodel.objects.get(name=post_data['cluster'])
post_data['name'] = cluster_object.name
post_data['zone'] = cluster_object.zone
form = forms.ClusterForm(post_data)
```

What we do here is that, we first send the name(preferably id) of cluster from post, then in the view we fetch the cluster object, retrieve name and zone, and include it in post_data and finally pass it to form.

Comment: I need to get multiple values from an option field!

Comment: meaning? could you elaborate on that

Answer (score 0):

> Its recommended to send `id` of cluster as value and fetch cluster object in your view.
>
> `<option value="{{cluster.id}}"></option>`

You can do it using *javascript*, but not with Django form submit it will always send `value` attribute of `<option>` tag to your views.

```
<select id="slc" name="cluster">
   <option value="{{cluster.id}}" c-name="{{cluster.name}}" c-zone="{{cluster.zone}}" > {{ cluster.name }}</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slc").change(function(){
            var selected_option = $('option:selected', this);
            var cluster_name = selected_option.attr('c-name');
            var cluster_zone = selected_option.attr('c-zone');
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### UPDATE

```js
$("#slc").change(function() {
  var selected_option = $('option:selected', this);
  var cluster_name = selected_option.attr('c-name');
  console.log("cluster_name:", cluster_name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="slc">
      <option c-name="volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
      <option c-name="saab" value="2">Saab</option>
      <option c-name="opel" value="3">Opel</option>
      <option c-name="audi" value="4">Audi</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to get values for cluster_name & cluster_zone in this way.

Comment: Check my update section i have added a code snippet, it is running fine.

Comment: Hey, @AbdulRehman, I was wondering, did this answers helped you?